# The same for loop produces a different result

Tags: java

I was working through a recursive problem where you want to print lines of m astericks until n astericks, then you want it to print down to m number of astericks. I see in the solution that the for loops are the same, but don't understand how this can be. I understand how the first for loop and recursion statement works, but what is it about the second loop that leads to the number of astericks decreasing each line? Please help with my understanding.

```
public class RecursionAstricks {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        printAstricks(3, 7);
    }

    public static void printAstricks(int m, int n) {
        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
        if (m < n) {
            printAstricks(m + 1, n);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that when calling the `printAstrics` function, while m < n, only the first loop will be executed. After m becomes equal to n, the second cycles of all previously called `printAstrics` functions will be executed in reverse order. I think the following representation is illustrative

```
call printAstrics(3, 7)
1) print 3 stars
2) call printAstrics(4, 7) (4 < 7)
    1) print 4 stars
    2) call printAstrics(5, 7) (5 < 7)
        1) print 5 stars
        2) call printAstrics(6, 7) (6 < 7)
            1) print 6 stars
            2) call printAstrics(7, 7)
                1) print 7 stars
                2) print 7 stars (7 !< 7, so do not call printAstrics(8, 7) and execute second loop)
            3) print 6 stars
        3) print 5 stars
    3) print 4 stars
3) print 3 stars
```